# Backend system for login not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP, still learning. When I click on submit for my login system I see no indication that the log-in details have been processed and sent to the MYSQL backend (the database named accounts). Can someone please help me and tell me why this is the case, it is supposed to re-direct to database-handler.php when sign up is clicked. Thanks in advance.

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>HappySocial</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">
    <div id="sign_up">
        <h2>Happy Social</h2>
        <form autocomplete="off" action="database-handler.php" method="POST">
        <input type = "text" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name">
        <br><br>
        <input type = "text" id="last_name" placeholder="Last Name">
        <br><br>
        <input type = "text" id="username" placeholder="Username">
        <br><br>
        <input type = "text" id="password" placeholder="Password">
        </form>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" id="sign_up_button" class="button"></>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="sign_in">
    <h3>Already have an account?</h3>
    <button id="sign_in_button" class="button">Sign In</button>
    </div>

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

database-handler.php:

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","password") or die("Unable to connect");
mysqli_select_db("accounts", $con);

?>
```

Comment: You are doing nothing with your mysql connection.

Comment: As mentioned, if this is all the code you have there’s nothing being done with the data you send from the client. You’ll have to add that still.

Comment: @Adam Please accept the answer which helped you most in solving your problem. It helps future readers. If the answers weren't helpful leave comments below them. So the poster can update them accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to execute a query on the database in order to retrieve data.

```
mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE user=x AND password=y");
```

---

Read more:

- [PHP Select Data From MySQL](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp)